# xml schema - child element dependant on parents attribute

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation

I stumbled upon a problem when i tried to something like this

```
<root>
    <ele type="a">
        <atr1>first</atr1>
    </ele>
    <ele type="b">
        <atr2>first</atr2>
    </ele>
</root>
```

when i was trying to enforce that givven element can only
have respective child elements if their attribute is set to respective values, that is inthis case, if it has "a", it can't have child .

But i can't really figure out how to do this in xml 1.0

Comment: I believe (but can't quote the spec at the moment) that you cannot do this. The best you could do would be to have `<ele_a>` and `<ele_b>` elements.

Comment: It should be possible to do somehow. Found stuff like that in some old lectures on xml but there were no solutions to them nor any explanation.

Comment: As @JimGarrison commented and Michael Kay answered, you cannot represent such constraints in XSD 1.0.  See duplicate link for how to do it using XSD 1.1's Conditional Type Assignment.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this kind of thing with XSD 1.0, it needs version 1.1: either assertions, or conditional type assignment will do the job.

Comment: Is there a way i can allow at least the existance of multiple versions? something like choice with sequence instead of single element?

Comment: You can make everything optional. But there is no way in XSD 1.0 to say "if this element is like this, then some other element must be like that".